# How to hide an old UINavigationController and replace it with another one?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

The first viewcontroller ***(A)*** contains a normal uinavigationcontroller with a backgroundcolor, then it pushes a new viewcontroller ***(B)*** with a transparent navcontroller. My first attempt is to modify the navcontroller appearance in ***B***, then reverse the original color for the uinavcontroller when B pops back to A. But it seems messed up the navcontroller appearance when I do transition push and pop between two views. So I came up with the idea is to replace the old one and add a complete brand new navcontroller. However the new navcontroller never display with the code below for some reasons ?

```
// Hide the old navigation controller
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

// Add a new one
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass: [TransparentNavBarView class] toolbarClass: [UIToolbar class]];
[nav.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems: [self buttonBarItems]];
[nav willMoveToParentViewController: self];
[self.view addSubview: nav.view];
[self addChildViewController: nav];
[nav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Any thoughts about my problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at how Navigation Controller works underneath.
Refer: [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

`UINavigationController` controls the appearance of the ViewControllers. When we push a viewcontroller, we actually pushes its view on the container view of Navigation Controller.
The navigation Bar for every view controller remains same.

You can get access to the `navigationBar` property in every view controller managed by the Navigation Controller by `self.navigationController.navigationBar`.

From Apple Docs:

> It is permissible to modify the barStyle or translucent properties of
>   the navigation bar but you must never change its frame, bounds, or
>   alpha values directly. To show or hide the navigation bar, you should
>   always do so through the navigation controller by changing its
>   navigationBarHidden property or calling the
>   setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for change `UINavigationBar.backgroundColor`. and call this method in `viewWillAppear` in which you want to change color of `NavigationBar`.

Add this method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[self barBackgroundImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And also this method in that viewController

```
-(UIImage*)barBackgroundImage{

    static UIImage *defaultImage = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(20, 44), NO, 0.0f);
        [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 44)] fill];
        defaultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    });

    return defaultImage;

}
```